# how does ssl_peek work ? is the behavior of ssl_peek same as MSG_PEEK of recv_msg

Tags: linux, network-programming, openssl

how does ssl_peek work ? is the behavior of ssl_peek same as that of MSG_PEEK flag ? i just want to read a few bytes of the payload and need to make a decision based on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it isn't the same. It requires that a complete SSL message has been received, containing application data, and that it has been decrypted. In the general case this won't be true, and when it is true it initiates the decryption and MAC-checking processes. So by comparison with MSG_PEEK it is less likely to return any data and more expensive to execute when it does so.

Comment: help me understand the last part of the message, so just to summarize the ssl_peek will read all the socket data in to user space and then decrypt the whole data and then will allow me to peek in to the data ? right now my stack just reads the first few bytes of the packet using MSG_PEEK and then splices the data to another socket.

Comment: The description in the 'man' page seems perfectly clear to me: "The SSL_peek() function copies num bytes from the specified ssl into the buffer buf".